# ASP.NET MVC Partial view data from an IEnumerable property of parent view's model data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, view, collections, model

How to assign a model property as the model data for a partial view?

I've a class called Album and some IEnumerable properties defined in it. I'm using `Dapper MultiMapping` for filling these properties

**Album Model**

```
namespace MusicStore.Model
{
    public class Album : IAlbum
    {
        int ID{get;set;}
        string Name {get;set;}
        ...
        IEnumerable<IPhoto> Photos{ get; set; }
        IDictionary<IArtistType, IList<IArtist>> Artists { get; set; }
    }

    public class Photos : IPhoto
    {
        int ID{get;set;}
        string URL {get;set;}
        ...
    }
}
```

**Album View**

```
@model MusicStore.Entity.IAlbum
...
@Partial("_PhotosPartial", @Model.Photos)
...
```

**_PhotosPartial partial view**

```
@model IEnumerable<MusicStore.Entity.IPhoto>
...
@if(Model!=null)
{
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <img id='img_@item.ID' src='\@item.URL' alt='@item.Title' />
    }
}
...
```

I want to use the property `IEnumerable<IPhoto> Photos` as model for the partial view.

> This works if the `IEnumerable<IPhoto> Photos` has at least one entry
>   in it, otherwise an exception occurs and it says I'm passing `IAlbum`
>   as model to `_PhotosPartial` partial view while it expects
>   `IEnumerable<IPhoto>` as its model.

Why am I getting this error?

I don't like using ViewModel 'coz an Album having a collection of photos makes more sense than using a separate ViewModel having an Album and a List of Photos as its properties like

```
public class AlbumViewModel
{
    public IAlbum Album { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<IPhoto> Photos{ get; set; }
    IDictionary<IArtistType, IList<IArtist>> Artists { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you initialize the `Photos` object only before adding items to it? I would also check if the `Photos` object is saved with the same name, somewhere in `ViewBag`. That gives back such crazy behavior...

Comment: Yeah, I initialize the Photos property only if there is any item to add to it, otherwise it will be null. I'm having the exception when `IEnumerable<IPhoto> Photos` is null.

Comment: Try to always initialize it. Even if there are no `IPhoto` objects stored, the object will still be accessible and "visible" in your view. It won't display anything as the `foreach` statement takes care of that. The main idea is to not send `null` as the model.